# Updating edittext from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I currently have the following situation:

1) The "main view" which contains the EditText I'm trying to update. (Let's call it `mainView`)

2) A fragment that is opened whenever I click in a button that is contained in the "main view", the 
fragment receives mainView as parameter.

3) An `OnClickListener` which is set to a button that is contained by the fragment. This listener receives the fragment as parameter.

Basically what I need to do is, each time I click on the button that triggers the listener, I need to update the editText, however it doesn't seem to be working. I believe it has something to do with "notifying" the view, but I haven't been able to get it working no matter what I try. After I update the text I close the fragment and

Basically the code is the following:

```
public void onClick(View v){
  String newMessageContent = "hello world";
  fragment1.mainView.editText1.setText(newMessageContent);
  FragmentManager manager = this.fragment1.getActivity().getFragmentManager();
  manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,this.fragment1.mainView.getPlaceHolderFragment()).commit();
}
```

Please note that I have simplified the problem a little bit and changed the name of the fragment/views in order for you guys to understand better. The text "hello world" is actually dynamic, and depends no another parameter that is received by the `OnClickListener`.

After I click the fragment does get replaced, so I know the `onClickListener` is working correctly, however I believe there's something wrong with the way the data change is being notified.

I've already looked at many SO questions, however none of them have helped me to achieve what I need.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: how are getting fragment1 reference?

Comment: In the constructor: public fragment1(MainView mainView)

Comment: not sure what you are saying. but just use fragment1 = getFragmentById() or fragment1 = getFragmentByTag() and then use getViewById() on that fragment1 to get your edittext id and hopefully that should solve your issue.

Comment: So basically the problem would be the reference? Let me give it a try, I still don't understand why it doesn't work though :(

Comment: The problem is that the edittext is on "mainView" though, not on fragment1.

Comment: if not in fragment, then just do mainView.findViewById(edittext-id-here) and then just update it. or even simply findViewById(edittext-id-here) should get the job done as well.

Comment: Please read my explanation again; I currently have the fragment open (it takes the whole screen), when I click on a button I try to set mainView back with fragmentManager, when I do this I need to change the text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64104/discussion-between-harikris-and-waclock).

Comment: did you have your answer? if not, i suggest you to create a callback from the fragment to your "mainView"

Comment: harikris lead me to the right direction :)

Comment: NeviQ-OR's suggestion is also elegant @Waclock.

Comment: if it's not so private, i'm curious to know how you solve that problem. i thought the interface/approach is the good way though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized the problem was that each time I replaced the fargment via the fragmentManager, the method setActivityView was being called again, which replaced the EditText content.

In order to avoid this, I manually removed the fragment (instead of replacing it), doing the following:

```
FragmentManager manager = this.selectTemplateFragment.getActivity().getFragmentManager();
manager.beginTransaction().remove(this.selectTemplateFragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest implementing an interface, say, IUpdateFromFragment with method, say, `onUpdate(String message)`, then let activity implement that interface and inside the fragment just call something like `((IUpdateFromFragment)this.getActivity()).onUpdate(newMessageContent);`

Comment: Thanks for your response; I actually tried something very similar, however it didn't work (I think) because of the reasons I stated on my answer.  Thanks again though!

Answer (score 0):

Update the fragment via transaction, then within the fragment1 class OnViewCreated, you can do mainView.editText1.setText("whatever");

The way you're doing this now, I'm surprised isn't throwing an exception since the view isn't inflated yet.